# Quarter values from previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, subquery

I had query, which working fine:

```
select t1.[Fiscal Year],
t1.[Level1], t1.[Level2], t1.[colE],t1.[colF],
t1.Value,t2.Value [previous_value]
from  
(  select [Fiscal Year],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF],sum([CA Service Bookings Net]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF]
)t1
left JOIN
(  
select [Fiscal Year],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF],sum([CA Service Bookings Net]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF]
)t2
ON t1.[Fiscal Year] = t2.[Fiscal Year]+1 and
t1.[Level1] = t2.[Level1] and
t1.[Level2] = t2.[Level2] and
t1.[colE] = t2.[colE] and
t1.[colF] = t2.[colF]
```

When I want to add more columns (colE, colF, colG...) it's ok.

But when I tried to add column: **[QuarterID]** contains value as: 2015Q1, 2015Q2, 2015Q3, 2015Q4, 2016Q1...

**t2.Value [previous_value] return me null values**. Do you know what can be reason?

Here is code with [QuarterID]:

```
select t1.[Fiscal Year],t1.[QuarterID],
t1.[Level1], t1.[Level2], t1.[colE],t1.[colF],
t1.Value,t2.Value [previous_value]
from  
(  select [Fiscal Year],[QuarterID],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF],sum([CA Service Bookings Net]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year],[QuarterID][Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF]
)t1
left JOIN
(  
select [Fiscal Year],[QuarterID],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF],sum([CA Service Bookings Net]) value
  from [table1] 
  group by [Fiscal Year],[QuarterID],[Level1],[Level2],[colE],[colF]
)t2
ON t1.[Fiscal Year] = t2.[Fiscal Year]+1 and
t1.[Level1] = t2.[Level1] and
t1.[Level2] = t2.[Level2] and
t1.[colE] = t2.[colE] and
t1.[colF] = t2.[colF] and
t1.[QuarterID] = t2.[QuarterID]
```

Comment: Where in the query are you adding [QuarterID]?

Comment: Im adding into exaclty the same places as for example Level1

Comment: Your column QuarterId is probably not joined properly. what are you joining it too?

Comment: please see my code with QuarterID into question (just added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just did it and working perfect:

```
t1.[Fiscal Quarter ID] = cast((cast(left(t2.[Fiscal Quarter ID],4) as numeric) +1) as varchar)+right(t2.[Fiscal Quarter ID],2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine you getting NULLS is if you either didn't correctly add QuarterID to the JOIN condition of t1 & t2, or if there are QuarterIDs that you expect to be found in t2, but that aren't there.

Are you joining in such a way that `2015Q1` in t1 will join to `2014Q1` in t2?   And do all the required quarterID's exist?

Comment: I have just updated question, now contains code with QuarterID column

Comment: Exactly the point of my last sentence.  You are joining on `t1.[Fiscal Year] = t2.[Fiscal Year]+1`   Don't you think you need to do something similar when you join `t1.[QuarterID] = t2.[QuarterID]`???    If the t1 QuarterId is `2014Q1`, wouldn't the t2 QuarterId have to be `2015Q1`???

Comment: ok, I have like: left([Fiscal Quarter ID],4)+right([Fiscal Quarter ID],2), how to increment first sentence by 1 year?

Comment: Cast/Convert the Left 4 to a numeric datatype and add 1.